# Python live coding/debugging

Tags: python, debugging

Is there a way to spawn an interactive python console (preferably iPython) during program execution *without pausing main program* and be able to check and modify program variables? Something similar to what browsers offer for JavaScript.

I know about `pdb.set_trace()` and `IPython.embed()`, but both of them pause program execution and require to place them somewhere in source code of the program.

This would be extremaly useful for desktop game development in python.

Comment: Also wonders if there's such methods. By the way `code.InteractiveConsole(locals=locals()).interact()` from pacakge `code` provides similar function like `IPython.embed()` but doesn't require IPython.

Comment: Minus the requirement that it has to spawn a console to change the variables, this sounds like a pretty standard debugger to me.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Indeed.  I would just use the free version of pycharm, if it doesn't interfere too much with performance. http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could roll-your-own somewhat with `threading`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def _spawn_background_interpreter(*args,**kwargs):
    from threading import Thread
    def _open_interp(locs):
        import code
        code.interact(local=locs)
    locs = args[0] if args else None
    t = Thread(target=_open_interp, args=(locs,))
    t.setDaemon(True) #pre-3.3 API
    t.start()
```

Call with `_spawn_background_interpreter(locals())`.

I haven't tested it, but this will *probably* be fine if your program doesn't continuously print things to the console - otherwise it will be all munged together with the interactive interpreter.

The "opening a new console" idea is interesting, but very environment-specific, so I won't tackle that.  I would be interested if there's a better prepackaged solution out there.

**Edit:** an attempt at a `multiprocessing` solution:

```
def _spawn_background_interpreter(*args,**kwargs):
    from multiprocessing import Process
    import sys, os
    def _open_interp(locs,stdin):
        import code
        sys.stdin = os.fdopen(stdin)
        code.interact(local=locs)
    locs = args[0] if args else None
    fileno = sys.stdin.fileno()
    p = Process(target=_open_interp, args=(locs,fileno))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
```

The reason I initially avoided `multiprocessing` is that each new process gets its own PID (and stdin).  Thus, I had to pass the main thread's stdin to the child process, and things get a little hacky from there.  **NOTE** that there is a bug in python 3.2 and lower that will cause tracebacks to spew any time you call `exit()` in a `multiprocessing` process.  This is fixed in 3.3.

Unfortunately, the `multiprocessing` code only runs on POSIX-compliant systems - i.e. not on Windows.  Not insurmountable, just going to require a more involved solution involving pipes.

Anyway the `multiprocessing` implementation is likely going to perform better for you if you're approaching 100% CPU utilization in your main thread.  Give it a try if you're on *nix.

Comment: This is very good, but the spawned console is not very responsive (runs very slowly), any idea why?

Comment: Ah, well your main thread is probably using at-or-near 100% CPU time.  The standard caveats of using threads in cPython apply. There's a good chance switching to multiprocessing could help. I'm away from my computer right now, will update when I get back.

Comment: @PythonFanboy mkay, gave a `multiprocessing` implementation a shot.  I'm not 100% happy with it, but ran out of time to sort out the kinks.  See if it's more performant.

Comment: @PythonFanboy turns out the reason I wasn't happy with it was a bug in python 3.2.  Heh.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Windows at the moment, but Python 3.3. If no other alternative will be available I will go with your answer (threads) and try to reduce CPU usage of my main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are familiar with PyDev running under Eclipse.  This provides excellent debugging capabilities if you are prepared to interrupt your main program (which is not what you want).  However PyDev has a feature called running a Debug Server which allows attaching to an existing running program.  I haven't tried it myself, but suggest you look at it, because PyDev is an excellent plugin for Eclipse.
If you try it, I'd be interested in your thoughts.
Try looking at:

```
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html
```

for details.  Good luck.