# raising SystemExit in a child process with redirected stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background:** I originally gave an answer to [this fine gentleman's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757232/python-live-debugging/19757873) about opening a non-blocking interactive interpreter mid-program using a `threading` solution.  He noted that it worked, but it performed poorly for him (understandable, because `threading`).  With trepidation, I turned to `multiprocessing` to achieve a more performant solution in the face of high CPU utilization.

The basic issue with using `multiprocessing` for this type of thing is that the child process does not share the main processes' STDIN - which I can work around, but...

**The Problem:** While I did arrive at a solution (see thread), there was one persistent issue with my solution: exiting the `code.interact()` session by calling `exit()` (i.e. raising `SystemExit`) gives this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 116, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test2.py", line 6, in interp
    code.interact(local=locs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/code.py", line 287, in interact
    console.interact(banner)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/code.py", line 223, in interact
    more = self.push(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/code.py", line 245, in push
    more = self.runsource(source, self.filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/code.py", line 74, in runsource
    self.runcode(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site.py", line 382, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 278, in _bootstrap
    sys.stderr.write(e.args[0] + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 132, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 126, in __init__
    code = process_obj._bootstrap()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 286, in _bootstrap
    util.info('process exiting with exitcode %d' % exitcode)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'exitcode' referenced before assignment
```

**Reproducing:** here is code to reproduce:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def interp(locs,handle):
    import code, os, sys
    sys.stdin = os.fdopen(handle)
    code.interact(local=locs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process
    import sys
    p=Process(target=interp,args=(locals(),sys.stdin.fileno()))
    p.start()
    import time
    time.sleep(20)
```

At the interactive interpreter you must type `exit()`.  Doing ctrl-D gracefully exits.  And here's the kicker: doing `raise SystemExit` **also** gracefully exits.  *What?!*

**Further Investigation:** here is the block that's having issues in `process.py`:

```
   except SystemExit as e:
        if not e.args:
            exitcode = 1
        elif type(e.args[0]) is int:
            exitcode = e.args[0]
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(e.args[0] + '\n') #exception here
            exitcode = 1
```

And inserting a debugging statement directly before that line shows that `e.args` is the length-1 tuple `(None,)`.  Makes sense, I guess.

**The Question:** what's going on?!  How is the version of `SystemExit` spawned by `exit()` getting a `(None,)` tuple for `e.args`?  This clearly doesn't happen normally - a bare `raise SystemExit` means that `e.args == ()`

I'm also willing to accept ways to improve my code (or my answer to the linked thread) but mostly I'm wondering if I'm doing something I explicitly shouldn't be doing.  Redirecting `sys.stdin` in a child process seems innocuous, but...

**Resolution:** thanks to Mr. Peters, turns out that this was a bug in python 3.2.  In 3.3 the offending line turned into: `sys.stderr.write(str(e.args[0]) + '\n')`.  `str(None) + '\n'` no longer causes explosions.  Cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no insight into your real problems here, but can clear up the `exit()` mystery.  It's documented behavior, here from the `site` module docs:

```
quit(code=None) 
exit(code=None) 
    Objects that when printed, print a message like “Use quit() or
    Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit”, and when called, raise SystemExit with
    the specified exit code
```

So `exit()` is the same as `exit(None)`, and that's where the `None` is coming from.  But there's something else!  `quit` and `exit` are instances of the `Quitter` class defined in `Lib/_sitebuiltins.py`, and have this `__call__` method:

```
def __call__(self, code=None):
    # Shells like IDLE catch the SystemExit, but listen when their
    # stdin wrapper is closed.
    try:
        sys.stdin.close()
    except:
        pass
    raise SystemExit(code)
```

It was a surprise to me that they close `sys.stdin`.  Relevant?  Don't know.  The comment implies it's a trick so that programs like IDLE know the user *really* wants to quit.

BTW, I'm looking at source code from the head of the current (3.4.0a4+) development branch, so there may be minor differences with the Python you're using.

Comment: Hey, interesting.  So changing my `interp` method to just `raise SystemExit(None)` (no fiddling with stdin required) reproduces the error.  Seems like a bit of a flaw in `process.py`.

Comment: Ah, geez.  And this looks like this was a bug in python 3.2.  In 3.3 the (no longer) offending line is `sys.stderr.write(str(e.args[0]) + '\n')`.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad it helped ;-) `multiprocessing` is still pretty delicate, in my experience - but I'm running on Windows, where your code won't run at all (`pickle` barfs when trying to pickle all the crud in `locals()` - no `fork()` on Windows).